# Incorrect Syntax near '(' SQL Server Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a table with variables from an ASP.NET form but it shows errors every time.

> incorrect Syntax near '('

C# Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,TableName,IdTab")] SsmsColumn ssmsColumn, string database, string nomtable)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ssmsColumn.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _context.Add(ssmsColumn);
            string primaryKey;
            string noNull;
            string colName = ssmsColumn.Title;
            string TableName = nomtable;
            string datatype = ssmsColumn.DataType;
            int? maxChar = ssmsColumn.CharacterMax;
            string charM = maxChar.ToString();
            bool Key = ssmsColumn.PrimaryKey.HasValue ? ssmsColumn.PrimaryKey.Value : false;
            bool nullable = ssmsColumn.IsNullable.HasValue ? ssmsColumn.IsNullable.Value : true;
            if (Key)
            { primaryKey = "PRIMARY KEY"; }
            else { primaryKey = ""; }
            if (nullable)
            { noNull = "null"; }
            else { noNull = "Not Null"; }
            string sql = " Use " + database + "; CREATE TABLE " + TableName + " (" + colName + " "+datatype+"(" + maxChar + ")" + primaryKey + " " + noNull +");";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["IdTab"] = new SelectList(_context.SsmsTable, "Id", "Title", ssmsColumn.IdTab);
        DataSet ds = dblayer.Get_Instance();

        ViewBag.database = ds.Tables[0];           
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
            "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
            "see your system administrator.");
    }

    //DataSet ds = dblayer.Get_Datatype();

    //ViewBag.datatype = ds.Tables[0];
    //ViewBag.nom = "hello";

    ViewBag.Tabname = TempData["Tabname"];

    List<SsmsTypeData> datatypelist = new List<SsmsTypeData>();
    datatypelist = (from product in _context.SsmsTypeData
                    select product).ToList();
    datatypelist.Insert(0, new SsmsTypeData { Id = 0, Title = "Select" });
    ViewBag.ListofType = datatypelist;

    return View();
}
```

My Form in View:

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-route-database="@ViewBag.dbname" asp-route-nomtable="@ViewBag.tabName" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.tabid">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    @*<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="IdTab" class="control-label">
                Table
            </label>
            <select asp-for="IdTab" class="form-control " asp-items="@ViewBag.IdTab" style="width: 100%;"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="IdTab" text-danger"></span>
        </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @*<select asp-for="IdBds" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.IdBds"></select>*@
        <input asp-for="IdTab" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.tabid" type="hidden" />
        <span asp-validation-for="IdTab" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Title" id="columname" name="columname" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TableName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="TableName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="TableName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IsNullable" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="isNull" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="IsNullable" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DataType" class="control-label"></label>
        <!--<input asp-for="DataType" class="form-control" />-->


        <select asp-for="DataType" name="dataType"
                class="form-control"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofType,"Id", "Title"))">
            --Select--
        </select>

        <span asp-validation-for="DataType" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PrimaryKey" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="primary" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="PrimaryKey" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CharacterMax" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CharacterMax" name="Mchar" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CharacterMax" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my debugger in visual studio it stops on the sql query and it does not create the table :

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44364/SsmsColumns/Create/5779dad1-80ae-4669-8f77-9e08f491f303?database=TestColumn application/x-www-form-urlencoded 314
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Create", controller = "SsmsColumns"}. Executing action pfeProject2020.Controllers.SsmsColumnsController.Create (pfeProject2020)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method pfeProject2020.Controllers.SsmsColumnsController.Create (pfeProject2020) with arguments (pfeProject2020.Models.SsmsColumn, TestColumn, ) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure:Information: Entity Framework Core 2.1.11-servicing-32099 initialized 'DBManagementContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Exception levée : 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' dans System.Data.SqlClient.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action pfeProject2020.Controllers.SsmsColumnsController.Create (pfeProject2020) in 642.5385ms
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost) : Chargé 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.7\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Chargement des symboles ignoré. Le module est optimisé et l'option du débogueur 'Uniquement mon code' est activée.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost) : Chargé 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.7\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Chargement des symboles ignoré. Le module est optimisé et l'option du débogueur 'Uniquement mon code' est activée.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost) : Chargé 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.7\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. Chargement des symboles ignoré. Le module est optimisé et l'option du débogueur 'Uniquement mon code' est activée.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '('.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at pfeProject2020.Controllers.SsmsColumnsController.Create(SsmsColumn ssmsColumn, String database, String nomt) in C:\Users\21692\Downloads\pfe2020-master\pfe2020-master\Controllers\SsmsColumnsController.cs:line 167
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at ...

Comment: Use your debugger and capture the string `sql` and add it to your question.

Comment: You need to stop the debugger *before* it attempts to run the code and inspect the **sql** variable and show us what it contains.

Comment: The complete error message is not helpful - it doesn't provide any additional information - I would suggest removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to be in this snippet:
`" (" + colName + " "+datatype+"(" + maxChar + ")"`

This will work for types taking one parameter, such as `varchar` or `char`, but will be a syntax error for types like `int` and `date` which don't take any parameters.

You will need to make the parentheses (both of them) conditional on whether or not the data type takes a `maxChar` parameter at all.

Comment: how to do that please